# Does Quicksort preserve the original order if the array is already sorted?

Tags: quicksort

I have an array that is sorted in most of the cases, but not always. So I still need to use an sorting algorithm to guarantee that the elements are in ascending order.

I know that QuickSort is not stable, so the relative order of elements with the same value may change. But I need to know if it preserves the original order of the elements in an array that is ALREADY sorted.

I'm using C++, so I can simply use std::stable_sort (MergeSort) instead of std::sort (QuickSort). But this is more a matter of curiosity than efficiency, as I couldn't find an answer to my question.

Comment: There are many varieties of quicksort with different properties, so the answer depends on which specific quicksort variety you're using. `std::sort` isn't even required to use quicksort! If you need stability, then use `stable_sort`, as you noted. `std::sort` does not guarantee stability.

Comment: Assuming typical implementations of either [Lomuto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) or [Hoare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme), then all values equal to the pivot are swapped, making these versions of quicksort unstable. For Lomuto, the running time gets worse as the number of duplicates increases. For Hoare, in spite of doing needless swaps on equal elements, the partitioning get closer to splitting in half, and running time generally decreases as the number of duplicates increases, assuming cached memory.